# Fancy Theorem Environment and Colors

Tags: tikz-pgf, lists, environments, color, theorems

I'm trying to make a boxed theorem environment with colors. 
I thought I had done it, but I was mistaken--lists were the wrong colors.

[image]

In the picture above, I would like the "list" to be the same color as the text.

Any suggestions would be welcome!

I've included sample code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{environ,tikz}

\NewEnviron{thm}{%
  \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=5pt,minimum width=\textwidth,
    text=white!93!brown!93!yellow, text opacity=1,
    draw=gray, ultra thick, draw opacity=1,
    fill=black, fill opacity=.7] 
  (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{.95\textwidth}
      \textbf{Theorem}\qquad\BODY
  \end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
Hello, check out my list:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Not the correct color\dots
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which colors are the ones you're trying to get?

Comment: @Mico - ah in the picture above, I want the list to be the same color as the text. I'm don't know why it isn't...

Comment: Just insert the instruction `\color{white!93!brown!93!yellow}` immediately after `\begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}`. This will also let you dispense with defining the text color as one of the options of the `\node` instruction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that `enumerate` and `itemize` reset font color. If you want to type all your `\BODY` with same color use `\color{white!93!brown!93!yellow}{\BODY}`.

Another option would be to use [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) which can use TikZ and draw colored theorems within boxes which can be broken between consecutive pages or columns.

Comment: `\color` has only one argument—i.e. the color name–so `\color{...}{\BODY}` would be the same as `\color{...} \BODY` (except that `\BODY` is in it's own group in the first case). But `mdframed` is a good advice.

Comment: Alternatively, you can define the desired color in the preamble with: `\colorlet{mycolor}{white!93!brown!93!yellow}` and then use it anywhere in the document.